# problem with setting up tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow

I installed latest version of tensorflow that is 2.3 and when i try to import tensorflow i get below error

```
runfile('C:/Users/Sriram/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sriram')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-ae532bb97ae9>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Sriram/untitled1.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sriram')

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 435, in runfile
    __umr__.run()

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\umr.py", line 133, in run
    if self.is_module_reloadable(module, modname):

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\umr.py", line 77, in is_module_reloadable
    if (path_is_library(getattr(module, '__file__', None),

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    from ._api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core'

Error in callback <bound method AutoreloadMagics.post_execute_hook of <autoreload.AutoreloadMagics object at 0x000001276F806208>> (for post_execute):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 538, in post_execute_hook
    _, pymtime = self._reloader.filename_and_mtime(sys.modules[modname])

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 184, in filename_and_mtime
    if not hasattr(module, '__file__') or module.__file__ is None:

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    from ._api.v2 import audio

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

  File "C:\Users\Sriram\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core'
```

I downloaded some msvdp71 zip file and extracted it and copied  it in my sys32 and syswow folders it didnt work for me.In colab i trained few models and i want to run them on pc when i try to run them with
tf1.6.0 they gave errors related to version .so when i upgraded it using pip i was not even able to import it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual environment in python. For the creation of a virtual environment, you need virtualenv library.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

After installing create your virtual environment.
command - **virtualenv "NAME-OF-ENVIRONMENT"**

eg

```
virtualenv myenv
```

This will create a directory called myenv. To activate the virtual environment you have go inside the myenv/scripts folder, open a cmd prompt and type activate.

eg

```
cd myenv/Scripts
activate
```

Get out of the Scripts folder

```
cd ../..
```

Now install TensorFlow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Tensorflow requires various libraries to work. As you know TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x are not compatible. When you ran the upgrade script it must have only upgraded the version and not downloaded the dependency.

Note: Always create a virtual environment when working in any project and keep your python package clean. You can delete these environments if they become corrupt or stop working correctly due to any reason, without and fear.